# How to add IF ELSE in mysql query

Tags: mysql, select

My query is like this

> ```
> select * from mytable where rank <= 10000 and priority = 1
> ```

I want to rewrite it like this.

- Select records which are under a specific value and priority is one.
- If no records found with priority = 1, then run the query without priority.

> ```
> select * from mytable where rank <= 10000
> ```

I know it can be done with php but can it can done in one query instead using php ?

thanks

Comment: using a single query or within a stored procedure?

Comment: single query please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more elegant or performant solution, but here's a simple option:

```
select * from mytable
 where rank <= 10000
   and (   priority = 1
        OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable
                        WHERE rank <= 10000
                          AND priority = 1
                      )
       )
;
```

This works as follows:  the `NOT EXISTS` statement will either evaluate to `TRUE` for every record where the rank meets our criteria, or to `FALSE` for every such record. So, if none of the records that meet our other criteria have `priority = 1`, this is `TRUE` for all those records, and all records that meet our other criteria will be returned.

If there *are* records that meet our other criteria and have `priority = 1`, then this statement will be `FALSE` for all records that meet our other criteria. In that case, only records where the other branch of the `OR` is `TRUE` - where `priority = 1` - will be returned.

NOTE: for this to work properly, the `NOT EXISTS` subquery must check *all* the query's criteria. If you actually want records where:

- `fieldA` is between Jan 1 2017 and March 31 2017; and
- `fieldB` is less than 240000

Then the query would have to be:

```
select * from mytable
 where fieldA >= '2017-01-01' AND fieldA < '2017-04-01'
   and fieldB < 240000
   and (   priority = 1
        OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable
                        WHERE fieldA >= '2017-01-01' AND fieldA < '2017-04-01'
                          AND fieldB < 240000
                          AND priority = 1
                      )
       )
;
```

Comment: will the OR do the job ?
SELECT ASIN FROM asins WHERE ReviewsNumUpdated<'2017-04-02 20:57:02' AND SalesRank<100000 OR Priority=1 LIMIT 0,10

Comment: @formul1 no, you must use not exists